# Cloning canvas is not working

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to clone the canvas element drawn by https://github.com/Kaiido/SVG2Bitmap/blob/master/SVG2Bitmap.js
library, and it is not working. The library successfully creates and appends `canvas` element to `html`, but when I try cloning it, it just appends empty `canvas` elements. Here is the code I am trying to use:

```
let svg = d3.select("div#main svg").node();
let canvas = d3.select("#canvas0")
                    .append("canvas")
                    .attr("width", 500)
                    .attr("height", 500)
                    .node();
SVG2Bitmap(svg, canvas);
this.props.datum.map((clusterObj, idx) => {
  if (idx > 0) {
    let canvasId = "div#canvas" + idx;
    let clonedCanvas = this.canvasClone(canvas);
    d3.select(canvasId)
      .append(function() {
        return clonedCanvas;
      });
  }
})
```

Apparently I am selecting the correct `div` tags with `d3` and appending `canvas` elements to them, but they are empty, nothing is drawn in them.
`canvasClone()` function was taken from: [Appending a div containing canvas is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46559050/appending-a-div-containing-canvas-is-not-working)

And is:

```
function canvasClone(c1) {
  var c2 = document.createElement('canvas');
  c2.width=c1.width;
  c2.height=c1.height;
  c2.getContext("2d").drawImage(c1, 0,0);
  return c2;
}
```

The only warning message that I see in the console is:

[image]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

> Update

I tried also:

```
let ctx =  c1.getContext("2d");
let imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
c2.getContext("2d").putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
```

And nothing happens, not working

> Update

I tried doing the following, considering that I can use the callback function, but it is still unsuccessfull:

```
let svg = d3.select("div#main svg").node();
SVG2Bitmap(svg, function(canvas) {
  this.props.datum.map((clusterObj, idx) => {
    let canvasId = "div#canvas" + idx;
    let clonedCanvas = this.canvasClone(canvas);
    d3.select(canvasId)
      .append(function() {
        return clonedCanvas;
      });
  })
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any way to clone HTML5 canvas element with its content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318565/any-way-to-clone-html5-canvas-element-with-its-content)

Comment: I tried almost identical solutions from the threads, and they are not working for me.

Comment: SVG2Bitmap is asynchronous, so when you try clone your canvas, nothing has been drawn on it yet. My bad this *lib* is not really user friendly, tbh I should probably have kept it limited to just resources fetching... Anyway, instead of your canvas, you can pass it a callback function, which will receive a drawn canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's my bad sorry, I made wrong design choices when writing this script...

The whole point of this script is to load all the external assets the svg element and its child do use in order to create a standalone document, drawable as is by `drawImage` method.

This means that the whole process will always be asynchronous, and hence my idea to pass something else than a callback function had very little sense, moreover when I didn't even allowed a way to pass both a receiver element **and** a callback function...

So first-of, sorry for my bad design choices in this now dead project. If I had to rewrite it (and maybe I will if I've got some time in the future), I would probably stick to fetching external assets and include it in the svg, letting the user choose what they want to do with it afterward.

---

But if you don't want to go through this ugly code yourself, you can workaround your issue quite easily.

The script does accept a callback function as receiver, on which the first argument will be a fresh `<canvas>`, with your svg already drawn on it.

```js
const this_props_datum = new Array(5).fill('foo');

let svg = d3.select("div#main svg").node();
SVG2Bitmap(svg, function callback(canvas) {
  this_props_datum.map((clusterObj, idx) => {
    let canvasId = "div#canvas" + idx;
    let clonedCanvas = this.canvasClone(canvas);
    d3.select(canvasId)
      .append(function() {
        return clonedCanvas;
      });
  })
});

function canvasClone(c1) {
  var c2 = document.createElement('canvas');
  c2.width = c1.width;
  c2.height = c1.height;
  c2.getContext("2d").drawImage(c1, 0, 0);
  return c2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Kaiido/SVG2Bitmap/a4ff9a91/SVG2Bitmap.min.js"></script>

<div id="main">
  <svg width=100 height=100 viewBox="0 0 40 40">
    <circle cx=20 cy=20 r="20" fill="url(#patt)"/>
  </svg>
</div>
<div id="canvas0"></div>
<div id="canvas1"></div>
<div id="canvas2"></div>
<div id="canvas3"></div>
<div id="canvas4"></div>

<!-- just to make the script useful... -->
<svg width="0" height="0" style="position:aboslute;z-index:-1;opacity:0">
  <defs>
  <pattern id="patt" x="0" y="0" width=".25" height=".25">
    <image width="10" height="10" xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fd/Ghostscript_Tiger.svg"/>
</pattern>
</defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: The only addition is that `this` will be undefined in it, so that I needed to do `var that = this`, and then `that.canvasClone()`